# Компиляция SFML из исходного кода для Windows с помощью MinGW+Cmake на ос Linux Fedora

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, sfml, mingw

пытаюсь скомпилировать SFML из исходного кода для Windows используя MInGW+Cmake на ос Linux Fedora. При попытке компиляции получаю вот такую ошибку:

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find Freetype (missing: FREETYPE_LIBRARY)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:600 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  cmake/Modules/FindFreetype.cmake:147 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  src/SFML/Graphics/CMakeLists.txt:117 (find_package)
```

Отмечу что установлен freetype-devel и если пытаться скомпилировать для Linux то все пройдет успешно.

Answer (score 0):

Вы же понимаете, что под винду нужно перекомпилировать *все* нужные библиотеки? Почему-то SFML вы компилируете сами, а не ставите из пакета (логично, потому что в пакете версия для линукса), а Freetype пытаетесь взять из пакета.

Пользуясь случаем, я бы посоветовал использовать свою [quasi-msys2](https://github.com/HolyBlackCat/quasi-msys2). Оттуда можно поставить уже собранный SFML для MinGW (и Freetype подянется как зависимость).